# Flag declined in review for reason that did not apply

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31354471/1541563) as "very low quality" because, as the comment on it states, it is quite unreadable. I found that my flag was reviewed and declined on the basis that:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This was not my issue with the answer, but that, as the flag description states:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

And this answer has both formatting *and* content problems, and the issue has nothing to do with the technical inaccuracy, or whether it is wrong. I fail to see how the reviewer can justify saying the flag did not apply.

Comment: Yeah... I would have deleted that. I mean, true, truly the true truth == (its truth truly == false).

Comment: On a side-note, do you have to have a certain amount of rep to see who reviewed your flag?

Comment: In the case of flags that are handled by moderators, no. The only way to know is if you post on meta and they answer. You will know a flag was handled by a moderator when the outcome contains a message.

Comment: it is true that your flag was truthfully correct and you were falsely declined.  Clearly a case of true true => false true.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like it's deleted now.

Comment: What is truth, when you really get down to it? The truth is unknowable because it is transient and subjective. The only absolute truth is that there are no absolute truths. This is what I mean when I tell you that existence is a prison.

Comment: @ChrisBaker `The only absolute truth is that there are no absolute truths` so are you lying or telling the truth?

Comment: @NathanOliver [mindexplosion.gif](http://www.gifwave.com/media/22589_explosion-cat-amazing-omg-reactions.gif)

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a statement. Don't use a question to make a statement.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @Mr.Chameleon! This is a question in the form that Patrick wants to know why their flag was declined. To do that, as there is no way to message a mod, they must bring it up here. You should check out [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) in the help center, where you'll get more of an explanation of how Meta Stack Overflow is different from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon I did tag it as "discussion"... it seemed odd at the time that my flag was declined and I wanted to make sure that my disagreement was sensible, so I posted about it here to find out if I was in the wrong.